# Tricky Django QuerySet with Complicated ForeignKey Traversals

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I am adapting Jim McGaw's e-commerce site from Beginning Django E-Commerce for my client's use.  My client sells builds of computers composed of a custom set of parts.  The parts that go into a system will change.  For instance, the Super Samurai system sold two years from now will have different parts than the one we sell tomorrow. So as we sell each Super Samurai system we need a snapshot of what parts went into the Super Samurai at the moment in time of the sale.

I am having a problem with the QuerySet that copies all of the parts from the table that maps parts to builds (i.e. the parts that go into the Super Samurai)...

```
class Build(models.Model):
    build = models.ForeignKey(PartModel, related_name='+')
    part = models.ForeignKey(PartModel, related_name='+')
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = ('build', 'part')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.build.name + ' with ' + str(self.quantity) + ' * ' + \
               self.part.family.make.name + ' ' + self.part.name

class BuildPart(Build):
    pass

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Build Part"
```

I need to copy the build parts from the BuildPart table into the OrderBuildPart table...

```
class OrderBuildPart(Build):
    orderItem = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ordered Build Part"
```

...so that in the future we know which parts went into so-and-so's build.

McGaw's e-commrece site doesn't allow for items to be bundles of other items.  So rather than create some nightmarish scenario of two different tables (and two series of SKUs) for builds and their parts, I wanted a build to be just like any other part...

```
class PartModel(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(PartFamily)
    name = models.CharField("Model Name", max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="http://www.Knowele.com/<b>*slug*</b>",
                            unique=True)
    vpn = models.CharField("VPN", help_text="Vendor's Part Number",
                               max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField("URL", blank=True, null=True)
    costurl = models.URLField("Cost URL", blank=True, null=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(help_text="How much knowele.com pays", max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(help_text="How much a customer pays", max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    isBestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isFeatured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isBuild = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    buildpart = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='BuildPart',
                                symmetrical=False, related_name='+')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = "Product Model"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('productdetail', args=[self.slug])
```

The buildpart field references the ManyToMany BuildPart table which allows a build to have many parts and for a part to be associated with many builds.

Through adapting McGaw's code I get pretty much what I need until I finalize the PayPal payment and try to record what parts went into the sold builds at the precise moment of sale...

```
def payment(request):
    token = request.POST['token']
    payer = request.POST['payer']

    result = paypal.do_express_checkout_payment(request, token, payer)

    if result['ACK'][0] in ['Success', 'SuccessWithWarning']:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=get_cart_id(request))
        finalOrder = Order()
        finalOrder.cart_id = get_cart_id(request)
        finalOrder.token = token
        finalOrder.corID = result['CORRELATIONID'][0]
        finalOrder.payerID = payer
        finalOrder.ipAddress = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        finalOrder.first = cart.first
        finalOrder.last = cart.last
        finalOrder.address = cart.address
        finalOrder.email = cart.email
        finalOrder.transactionID = result['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID'][0]
        finalOrder.status = 'f'
        finalOrder.save()

        for item in get_cart_items(request):
            oi = OrderItem()
            oi.cart_id = item.cart_id
            oi.quantity = item.quantity
            oi.product = item.product
            oi.price = item.price()
            oi.save()

            if item.product.isBuild:
                for part in get_build_parts(request, item):
                    bp = OrderBuildPart()
                    bp.build = part.build
                    bp.part = part.part
                    bp.quantity = part.quantity
                    bp.orderItem = oi
                    bp.save()

        empty_cart(request)

        return render(request, 'payment.html', locals())
```

Everything seems fine until we hit the get_build_parts function...

```
def get_build_parts(request, part):
    return BuildPart.objects.filter(build__id=part__product__pk)
```

...where Django's post-mortem complains "NameError at /payment/ global name 'part__product__pk' is not defined"

How do I traverse these complicated relationships so my boss can look up what parts went into each customer's builds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value side of the lookup doesn't work the way you think it does. The double-underscore stuff is for the left-hand side only: in effect, it's a hack to get round Python's syntax requirements. On the right-hand side, you pass a normal expression, which can follow object relationships using the standard dot syntax:

```
return BuildPart.objects.filter(build__id=part.product.pk)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `BuildPart.objects.filter(build=part__product)` instead of what you have.

Also, it looks like your "post mortem" is coming from the webapp actually being used. You should be learning of problems like this from unit tests failing, not from an HTTP call.